# Code giving me duplicate values if string greater than 6 characters. Fine with strings with 1-6 characters...

Tags: java

```
public class PossibleCombination {

     public static void comb(String s) {
       int N = s.length();
       char[] a = new char[N];
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           a[i] = s.charAt(i);
       comb(a, N);
    }

    private static void comb(char[] a, int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println( a);
            return;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            swap(a, i, n-1);
            comb(a, n-1);
            swap(a, i, n-1);
            }
    }  
    private static void swap(char[] a, int i, int j) {
        char c;
        c = a[i]; 
        a[i] = a[j]; 
        a[j] = c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String alphabet = "sparowsd";
       System.out.println();
       comb(alphabet);
    }  
}
```

What what changes do I have to make so the program does not give duplicated values?

My code giving me duplicate values (if string greater than 6 characters)... It's fine with strings with 1-6 characters... Where do I have to make changes?
Thanks!

Comment: I notice your alphabet String has two "s" characters.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it suppose to be a word "password" after making possible combinations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program generates duplicates but that's OK as you have two 's' characters in the String "password". That's what Elliot Frisch meant, I am pretty sure. Try your program on the string "12345678". It should not generate any duplicates on it. But if you try it on the string "12345671", it will, as you have two characters '1' in it. So your program seems good, it generates all permutations of the input string.

If you want to get rid of the duplicates you need a different algorithm. Try this one.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

Comment: thanks both of u..@Elliot i got it... it just replace "s" with other "s" and it seems to be duplicate...

Comment: that's correct, it doesn't make distinction between the two 's' chars, so you get the duplicates